# Efficient way to introduce index to hashmap in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hashmap

I am having a requirement to apply index to hashmap in MongoDB. After going through few answers in Stackoverflow, I came to know that we can apply index to each key in HashMap. But the overhead is extra storage space. Is there any way to create index in hashmap . So that , the new key introduction will also be taken care.

Comment: You might try a wildcard index.

Comment: If you have a requirement to apply index - apply index and fulfil the requirement. Any index has overhead to store indexed data, you cannot get an index for free. Could you elaborate what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Hope , wildcard index is the correct option in this case.